# How to decompress splited files (from one compressed one) located in different directories?

Tags: split

I have a problem in decompressing file in Ubuntu.
Here, I have huge amount of compressed file (test.tar.gz) which is nearly 1.2 TB and resultantly becomes 3 TB after decompressing.

I have only 4 TB and 1 TB SSD so that I cannot decompress the file in a single SSD.

So, my point is;

1. How to split the (already) compressed file into several parts? (for example, splitting into 2 files, both of which are 600 GB)
2. After that, I have to locate those files into different directories due to the amount problem. Then, How to decompress those files into a single directory even if they are located at the different directories?

Comment: "How to decompress splited files (from one compressed one)"  that are possible. You need to merge the split files and can them decompress.

Comment: What may work is to `cat` the parts of the archive to standard output, then have tar decompress the standard input

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split` command :) If you want 2 files use `-n` with 2:

```
split test.tar.gz -n 2
```

Joining can be done with `cat`:

```
 cat x* > test2.tar.gz
```

will merge all files starting with `x` into `test2.tar.gz`
Replace `x*` by the 2 files (and add directories).

Mind that you will need about double the space if all are on the same partition.

Answer (score 0):

Split the tarball gzipped archive into two file and put one in the smaller SSD and the other into the bigger SSD;
assuming your smaller SSD is mounted to /mnt/smallerSSD and the other SSD to /mnt/biggerSSD:

```
split -b 800M test.tar.gz test.tar.gz.part.
mv test.tar.gz.part.aa /mnt/smallerSSD
mv test.tar.gz.part.ab /mnt/biggerSSD
```

This will create two files test.tar.gz.part.aa and test.tar.gz.part.ab respectively of 800MB and about 400MB (sum is 1.2TB) and put them each in a different SSD. If you have less than 800MB of free disk space in your smaller SSD, use a smaller value.

Then, using cat and tar, proceed to extract the whole archive into the bigger SSD

```
cd /mnt/biggerSSD
cat /mnt/smallerSSD/test.tar.gz.part.aa /mnt/biggerSSD/test.tar.gz.part.ab | tar -xvz
```

This may not work if the free disk space is not enough; in that case you could use netcat/ssh to transfer (and then retrieve) some parts from the other devices in the local network, or else, you could use a more aggressive compression algorithm for your tarballs (e.g. bzip2) but this will result in longer compression/decompression times.